# Update Angular material version

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need the info about angular material version. Specially I developed a solution with the **"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8"** and it work very well. Now I don't want change the name of component in my application: ex.
 if now I'm installing the **new version of angular material** "@angular/material @angular/cdk" is necessary to change all components **prefix** **'md'** into **'mat'**. Ther's a way to save the old components already existent in my application with 'md' prefix and to use the new component **"import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material'"** ?

Answer (score 0):

thank you. the npm prefix Updater worked fine but the application now not working fine. The update compromised the router-outlet too. Please could you tell me where i can found the mdstepper or samething that same? Thank you again